# Not enough resources for query planning

Tags: google-bigquery

When creating an ML model using BigQuery ML, I get an error like this:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.

I could create the same model with the same data set 1 month ago without error. What could be the reason?

```
CREATE MODEL
  `myproject.ml_table.persona_03092019`
OPTIONS
  ( model_type='kmeans',
    num_clusters=3, distance_type='COSINE' ) AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(id)
FROM `myproject.scratch.persona_df_03092019`
```

Comment: how much data it is in your table?

Comment: As you were able to run the same model with this dataset 1 month ago, the issue may be related to the size of it, if it has grown in the past month. If the query is too complex or are a lot of resources to be used, the query planner can decide to not run the query and return this error. You can see more about the resourced exceeded error in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#resourcesExceeded).

Comment: Are the number of clusters and the distance metric the same as the one you were able to run earlier?

Answer (score 0):

based on the information provided, what bhito@ and Gursel@ suggested are potential reasons. Currently, BQML provides more details in the error message. And please feel free to reach out to us.